# Why Building walls disappear when rotating camera in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3D URP project. I have 2 scenes. 1st view is the outside view of a building. 2nd view is the inside view of the building.on scene 1, when I click the building, I load my 2nd scene.2nd scene has a separate camera.This is my main camera on 2nd view.
[image]

My problem is, in 2nd view, when I rotate the camera, building walls are disappearing. I tried turning off `Occlusion Culling`, decreasing and increasing `Clipping Planes Near` and increasing `Far. Whatever I do the problem still persists. What is the reason for this and how should I resolve this? When I hit Play button on Unity editor, this problem doesn't happen on Game View. Only when build & run externally it happens.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

this only happens when I switch to scene 2 from scene 1. If I load the 1st scene initially, then this doesn't happen. Also I am using 2 cameras for scene 1 and scene 2

Comment: Resolved this by copying the same camera from scene 1 to scene 2